# save image automatically from src

Tags: javascript, html, image, save, src

I have an array with src url of a lot of images and I need to automatically save them.
This is the situation: There is a website, which I have tha utorization to download all the images but there isn't a way to do that automatically, so I thouth to lauch a script from the consol and take the src of all images with a particular class. This is my code:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("large-screenshot"); 
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) { 
    console.log(imgs.item(i).getAttribute('src')); 
}
```

now I want to save the images shown throught that links. How can I do that???

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you did this outside the browser? Here's what I would do: once I have the list of urls, I would put toghether a quick bash (or whatever in your OS) script that downloads the files using `curl` or `wget`.

Comment: what do you mean by saying saving images, do you want to save them in your database ?

Comment: You can't do multiple downloads from Javascript, for obvious reasons.  You can create links from all the images that will trigger a download when clicked, but you'd have to click them all yourself.